# How do I trigger a function with whatever table row I just dropped in jQuery UI Sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working with jQuery UI Sortable plugin, and applying it to a table. How would I trigger a function when dropping whatever element I am dragging? Something similar to below:

```
alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

---

Full Solution

For this, you have to set the container id's to something_number (something_1, something_2, etc).

```
$(function(){
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
        update: function(event, ui){
            var order = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');
            alert(order);
        }
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily be using **stop** event. Details are documented [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#event-stop).

Quick example:

```
$( "#your-id" ).sortable({
   stop: function(event, ui) { 
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
   }
});
```

You can alternatively give a try to other events like **update** depending on what are you needs exactly.